# Non-static method App\User::add() should not be called statically

Tags: php, laravel

Выдаёт ошибку в строке `$user = User::add($request->all()`.

Весь метод:

```
public function store(Request $request)
        {
            $this->validate($request, [
                'name' => 'required',
                'email' => 'required|email',
                'password' => 'required',
                'avatar' => 'nullable|image'
            ]);

            $user = User::add($request->all());
            $user->uploadAvatar($request->file('avatar'));

            return redirect()->route('users.index');
        }
```

Comment: метод `add` класса `User` не статический, а значит его нельзя вызывать как `User::add`. Только через объект

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`::`](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.paamayim-nekudotayim.php) работает только для статических методов/констант.

Либо сделайте его статическим, либо прокиньте ссылку в метод, чтоб вызвать метод:

```
$user = $userObj->add($request->all());
```

Если у вас `store` в классе `User`, то делайте так:

```
$user = self::add($request->all());
```